# How to format metadata for Lucid?

Tags: nft, metadata, transaction-metadata, lucid

Our metadata as a CIP 25 looks like this:
[Pool pm metadata tool](https://pool.pm/test/metadata?metadata=%257B%2522721%2522%253A%257B%2522f034c6a258b24515a3fd848c5015df52ed1d38971be57aad83e808e7%2522%253A%257B%2522Origin%2520Certificate%2522%253A%257B%2522description%2522%253A%255B%2522Village%2520Los%2520Hornos%252C%2520Comayagua%2522%252C%2522Country%2520Honduras%2522%252C%2522Grower%2520Nelvin%2520Humberto%2520Vaquis%2522%252C%2522SCA%2520Grade%252085%2522%252C%2522Altitude%25205245%2520ft%2522%252C%2522Variety%2520Parainema%252C%2520PACA%2520and%2520H-90%2522%252C%2522Characteristic%2520citrus%2520flavor%2522%252C%2522Floral%2520tones%2522%252C%2522Bean%2520Medium%2520Complexion%2522%255D%252C%2522files%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522mediaType%2522%253A%2522image%252Fpng%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Origin%2520Certificate%2522%252C%2522src%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Farweave.net%252F8Jz956OMtQeORPXlDVdp9QYDIQVQd5QqtpMc3wGr1IE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522image%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Farweave.net%252F8Jz956OMtQeORPXlDVdp9QYDIQVQd5QqtpMc3wGr1IE%2522%252C%2522mediaType%2522%253A%2522image%252Fpng%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Origin%2520Certificate%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522version%2522%253A%25221.0%2522%257D%257D)

We are using Lucid to attach it during transaction building in this way:

```
const filename= "https://arweave.net/" + arweaveId
      const metadata = {
        [policyId]: {
          "Origin Certificate": {
            "description": [
                "Village": "Los Hornos, Comayagua",
                "Country": "Honduras",
                "Grower": "Nelvin Humberto Vaquis",
                "SCA Grade": "85",
                "Altitude": "5245 ft",
                "Variety": "Parainema, PACA, & H-90",
                "Characteristic": Citrus Flavor, Floral Tones",
                "Bean": Medium Complexion"
            ],
            "files": [
               {
                  "mediaType": "image/png",
                  "name": "Origin Certificate",
                  "src": filename
               }
            ],
            "image": filename,
            "mediaType": "image/png",
            "name": "Origin Certificate"
          }
      },
      version: "1.0"
      };
```

But something exceeds the character limit even though none of the strings exceed 64 characters. Also, removing the quotation marks removes the error about the character limit but the metadata doesn't format correctly.
To attach the metadata we do the following:

```
.attachMetadata(721, metadata)
```

What could we change to eliminate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, file links are too long. Have you tried shortening links, or using different file hosting service?

Try something that looks more this: [Pool pm metadata tool](https://pool.pm/test/metadata?metadata=%257B%2522721%2522%253A%257B%2522f034c6a258b24515a3fd848c5015df52ed1d38971be57aad83e808e7%2522%253A%257B%2522Origin%2520Certificate%2522%253A%257B%2522description%2522%253A%255B%2522Village%2520Los%2520Hornos%252C%2520Comayagua%2522%252C%2522Country%2520Honduras%2522%252C%2522Grower%2520Nelvin%2520Humberto%2520Vaquis%2522%252C%2522SCA%2520Grade%252085%2522%252C%2522Altitude%25205245%2520ft%2522%252C%2522Variety%2520Parainema%252C%2520PACA%2520and%2520H-90%2522%252C%2522Characteristic%2520citrus%2520flavor%2522%252C%2522Floral%2520tones%2522%252C%2522Bean%2520Medium%2520Complexion%2522%255D%252C%2522files%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522mediaType%2522%253A%2522image%252Fpng%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Origin%2520Certificate%2522%252C%2522src%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Ftinyurl.com%252Fyneyp82d%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522image%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Ftinyurl.com%252Fyneyp82d%2522%252C%2522mediaType%2522%253A%2522image%252Fpng%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Origin%2520Certificate%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522version%2522%253A%25221.0%2522%257D%257D).